# Hollow cube in a flat array

Tags: arrays, geometry

Given a cube of values it is easy to fit it into a flat array and perform lookups using the index found by x*l*l+y*l+z, where l is the side length. However I have not found a solution for when the cube is hollow. I could just use a full cube in the array and ignore some cells, however the memory requirements to store a cube in an array is n^3 as opposed to 6n^2. Memory is important in this application. I would be very thankful if somebody could point me towards a way to index such a hollow cube of values

Comment: How about using an object (use "index" as key)?  
For example: `var cube={1:1, 2:8, 3:27, 4:64}` or, the reverse: `var cube={1:1, 8:2, 27:3, 64:4}`

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called `CUBE_MAP`... nowadays gfx cards have native HW implementation for textures in this mode... However cube maps are not addressed by index instead they use direction vector from the cube center. And where the vector points that texel is fetched.

I am using cube maps also for CPU side geometry code for speeding up some geometric algorithms like finding OBB...

Here a simple C++ class I use for this:

```cpp
template<class T,int N> class cube_map3D
    {
public:
    int n,nn,sz;
    float fn2;
    T map[6*N*N];

    // zoomed cube map (covers only zoomed area near tan,nor,bin directions)
    vec3 tan,nor,bin;   // normalized directions
    float zoom;         // zoom

    cube_map3D()    { n=N; nn=N*N; sz=6*nn; fn2=0.5*float(n); initzoom(vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0),1.0); }
    cube_map3D(cube_map3D& a)   { *this=a; }
    ~cube_map3D()   {}
    cube_map3D* operator = (const cube_map3D *a) { *this=*a; return this; }
    //cube_map3D* operator = (const cube_map3D &a) { ...copy... return this; }

    vec3 ix2dir(int ix)
        {
        float x,y;
        vec3 dir=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        if ((ix<0)||(ix>=sz)) return dir;
        x=ix%n; ix/=n; x/=fn2; x--;
        y=ix%n; ix/=n; y/=fn2; y--;
        if (ix==0){ dir.y=x; dir.z=y; dir.x=-1.0; }
        if (ix==1){ dir.y=x; dir.z=y; dir.x=+1.0; }
        if (ix==2){ dir.x=x; dir.z=y; dir.y=-1.0; }
        if (ix==3){ dir.x=x; dir.z=y; dir.y=+1.0; }
        if (ix==4){ dir.x=x; dir.y=y; dir.z=-1.0; }
        if (ix==5){ dir.x=x; dir.y=y; dir.z=+1.0; }
        return normalize(dir);
        }
    int dir2ix(vec3 dir)
        {
        int ix=0,x,y;
        float a=0.0,b,c;
        b=fabs(dir.x); if (a<b){ a=b; if (dir.x<0) ix=0; else ix=1; }
        b=fabs(dir.y); if (a<b){ a=b; if (dir.y<0) ix=2; else ix=3; }
        b=fabs(dir.z); if (a<b){ a=b; if (dir.z<0) ix=4; else ix=5; }
        b=0.0; c=0.0;
        if (ix==0){ b=dir.y; c=dir.z; }
        if (ix==1){ b=dir.y; c=dir.z; }
        if (ix==2){ b=dir.x; c=dir.z; }
        if (ix==3){ b=dir.x; c=dir.z; }
        if (ix==4){ b=dir.x; c=dir.y; }
        if (ix==5){ b=dir.x; c=dir.y; }
        b=((b/a)+1.0)*fn2; x=b;
        c=((c/a)+1.0)*fn2; y=c;
        ix=(ix*nn)+(y*n)+(x);
        if ((ix<0)||(ix>=sz)) ix=0;
        return ix;
        }
    vec3 ix2dirzoom(int ix)
        {
        float x,y;
        vec3 dir=vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
        if ((ix<0)||(ix>=sz)) return dir;
        x=ix%n; ix/=n; x/=fn2; x--; x/=zoom;
        y=ix%n; ix/=n; y/=fn2; y--; y/=zoom;
        if (ix==0){ dir.y=x; dir.z=y; dir.x=-1.0; }
        if (ix==1){ dir.y=x; dir.z=y; dir.x=+1.0; }
        if (ix==2){ dir.x=x; dir.z=y; dir.y=-1.0; }
        if (ix==3){ dir.x=x; dir.z=y; dir.y=+1.0; }
        if (ix==4){ dir.x=x; dir.y=y; dir.z=-1.0; }
        if (ix==5){ dir.x=x; dir.y=y; dir.z=+1.0; }
        dir=(dir.x*tan)+(dir.y*nor)+(dir.z*bin);
        return normalize(dir);
        }
    int dir2ixzoom(vec3 dir)
        {
        int ix=0,x,y;
        float a=0.0,b,c;
        dir=vec3(dot(dir,tan),dot(dir,nor),dot(dir,bin));
        b=fabs(dir.x); if (a<b){ a=b; if (dir.x<0) ix=0; else ix=1; }
        b=fabs(dir.y); if (a<b){ a=b; if (dir.y<0) ix=2; else ix=3; }
        b=fabs(dir.z); if (a<b){ a=b; if (dir.z<0) ix=4; else ix=5; }
        b=0.0; c=0.0;
        if (ix==0){ b=dir.y; c=dir.z; }
        if (ix==1){ b=dir.y; c=dir.z; }
        if (ix==2){ b=dir.x; c=dir.z; }
        if (ix==3){ b=dir.x; c=dir.z; }
        if (ix==4){ b=dir.x; c=dir.y; }
        if (ix==5){ b=dir.x; c=dir.y; }
        b=((b*zoom/a)+1.0)*fn2; x=b;
        c=((c*zoom/a)+1.0)*fn2; y=c;
        ix=(ix*nn)+(y*n)+(x);
        if ((ix<0)||(ix>=sz)) ix=0;
        return ix;
        }
    void set(vec3 dir,T &a){        map[dir2ix(dir)]=a; }
    T    get(vec3 dir     ){ return map[dir2ix(dir)];   }
    void setzoom(vec3 dir,T &a){        map[dir2ixzoom(dir)]=a; }
    T    getzoom(vec3 dir     ){ return map[dir2ixzoom(dir)];   }
    void initzoom(vec3 dir,float _zoom)
        {
        tan=normalize(dir);
        nor=vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0);
        if (fabs(dot(tan,nor))>0.75) nor=vec3(0.0,1.0,0.0);
        bin=normalize(cross(tan,nor));
        nor=normalize(cross(bin,tan));
        zoom=_zoom;
        }
    void clear(const T &a){ for (int i=0;i<sz;i++) map[i]=a; }
    };
```

so you just declare it like this:

```
cube_map3D<float,64> cm;
```

that will make cube map of `6x64x64` floats. This is how to access it with direction:

```
cm.map[cm.dir2ix(vec3(0.1,0.2,0.3))]=5;
```

`ix2dir` will generate direction from index (so you can enumerate all directions for example ...).

zoom functions are there to iteratively enhance precision for angle searching algorithms (with zoom the sides will not cover full angle sweep but only its fraction enhancing angular precision without the need to allocate huge amounts of memory).

`tan,nor,bin` are the cube axises direction so it can be aligned to specific directions.